# NaN total value of select sum in angular

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

In my project I've a problem with the value of the select. I don't know why, the select show me only the last value, and the multiplication of the value with the input show me a `NaN` result.
Also I would like to ask if differentiating `price` in different classes (`priceAAB`,`priceFG`) is the best solution? Because I have both classes with equal `value` (`priceAAB` for example does not have `D0` and `D1`), but with different `price`. These selections should appear based on the type of `risk` I am going to select at the top of the page

**summary.ts**

```
//risk: string = "C"
  risk: string = "D"
  userNumber: number
  intoSelectPrice: number = 0
  total: number = 0
  

  priceAAB: PriceAAB[] = [
    { id: 1, value: "D2", price: 240 },
    { id: 2, value: "D3", price: 840 },
    { id: 3, value: "D4", price: 1200 },
    { id: 4, value: "D5", price: 1200 }
  ]

  priceFG: PriceFG[] = [
    { id: 1, value: "D0", price: 840 },
    { id: 2, value: "D1", price: 840 },
    { id: 1, value: "D2", price: 1080 },
    { id: 2, value: "D3", price: 1200 },
    { id: 3, value: "D4", price: 1200 },
    { id: 4, value: "D5", price: 1200 }
  ]

  sum() {
    if(this.risk == "C") {
      let price: number
      this.priceAAB.forEach(a => {
          price = a.price
      })
      this.intoSelectPrice = price
      this.total = price * this.userNumber
    } else if(this.risk == "D") {
      let price: number
      this.priceFG.forEach(a => {
          price = a.price
      })
      this.intoSelectPrice = price
      this.total = price * this.userNumber
    }
  }
  
}

export class PriceAAB {
  id: number
  value: string
  price: number
}

export class PriceFG {
  id: number
  value: string
  price: number
}
```

**summary.html**

```html
<input type="number" [value]="userNumber">mq

<select *ngIf="risk == 'C'">
  <option [ngValue]="array.price" *ngFor="let array of priceAAB">{{array.value}}: {{array.price}}
  </option>
</select>
<select *ngIf="risk == 'D'">
  <option [ngValue]="array.price" *ngFor="let array of priceFG">{{array.value}}: {{array.price}}
  </option>
</select>

<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)=sum()>Go
</button>
<br>
Number in select: {{intoSelectPrice}}<br>
Total: {{total}}
```

I also add the link to stackblitz --> [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kcwgk3?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: if we omit the terrible use of for each inside the sum function, you are simply not assigning any initial value to the userNumber property, which you use as a multiplier of the price in `this.total = price * this.userNumber` thus resulting in NaN,

Comment: @Krzysztof how i can assign a value of userNumber in input object?

Comment: userName is in an input, can be a a string, be sure and convert to number, you can use `+` : `this.total = price * (+this.userNumber)`.

Comment: NOTE: use some like `this.intoSelectPrice=this.priceAAB.reduce((a:number,b:any)=>(a+b.price),0)` to sum the prices of the arrays

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues here.

1. You need to bind the value from the template `<input>` element to reuse it in the controller. Quickest way would be to two-way bind the element using `ngModel`.

```html
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="userNumber">
```

2. Implement some form of validation to prevent calling the `sum()` function when the `<input>` field is empty.

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!userNumber" (click)=sum()>Go
</button>
```

3. The `sum()` function could be simplified using `Array#reduce` instead of `forEach` to perform the summation.

```js
sum() {
  const priceSelected = this.risk == "C" ? this.priceAAB : this.priceFG;
  this.intoSelectPrice = priceSelected.reduce((acc, curr) => (acc += curr.price), 0);
  this.total = this.intoSelectPrice * this.userNumber;
}
```

I've adjusted your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wchgwt?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I like this solution.  (acc += curr.price), 0); sets initial value to zero and accumulates the total price all on one line

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting NaN because you're not initializing number in your sum() function? Instead of doing this: `let price: number`  should you be doing this `let price: number = 0` ?

Additionally, instead of using `price = a.price` should you be using `price += a.price` ?

Comment: with `let price: number = 0` the value of `{{intoSelectPrice}}` remains wrong, going to always select the last select (1200), and the `{{total}}` show me always `NaN`

Comment: Hi Daniele!  :  )

Did also trying this work?  price += a.price